# stable_baselines 3 doesn't store the tensorboard_log

Tags: python, stable-baselines

I am just getting into reinforcement learning. My Model doesn't create any files in the given directory. What am i doing wrong?

```
def train():
    model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)

    model.learn(total_timesteps=3000)
    with open(os.path.join(log_path,"Text.txt")) as file: #Test if given directory works
        print(file.read())

    model.save(PPO_Path)
```

The trained model does work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

`model.learn()` function should have additional parameter `tb_log_name`

Like this:

```
model.learn(total_timesteps=3000, tb_log_name="experiment_1")
```